# bash command to get distribution and version only

Tags: centos, command-line, version, conky

I am trying to get the distribution name and version number to enter into conky.  I am currently using the following

```
rpm --query centos-release
```

resulting in

```
centos-release 7-4.1708.e17.centos.x86_64
```

How do I pare that down to just `centos 7-4.1708.e17`?

After trying all the suggestions I ended up entering this into my conky

```
${font Roboto:bold:size=8}${goto 95}${color1}Distribution $alignr   ${execi > 60 a=$(rpm --query centos-release)
a=${a#centos-release }
a=${a%%\.centos.*}
echo "$a"}
```

with this result

```
centos-release-7-4.1708.e17
```

Comment: Should we assume you meant there to be a hyphen between `centos` and `7-4` in both instances?  Standard RPM names don't have spaces.

Comment: Also, you wrote `e17`, but I suspect you meant `el7`.  Copying and pasting is *far* preferable to retyping.

Comment: Do you want the version of the RPM, or the version of the distribution? They are different.

Comment: I could not find a way to copy out of the terminal so yes el7.  I release spaces are not the norm but as this is just for reference I find it much easier to read so I would like the space but not super important. I am not 100% sure on the version of the RPM or distribution but the outcome I am looking for is centos 7-4.1708.el7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ rpm --query centos-release | sed 's/^centos-release//;s/\.centos.*//'
7-4.1708.e17
```

---

With only shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$(rpm --query centos-release)
a=${a#centos-release }
a=${a%%\.centos.*}
echo "$a"
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach to printing the names and details of RPM packages in customized formats is the `--qf` or `--queryformat` option to the `rpm` command.

To quote `man rpm` in part:

> Query formats are
>          modified versions of the standard printf(3) formatting.  The  format
>          is made up of static strings (which may include standard C character
>          escapes for  newlines,  tabs,  and  other  special  characters)  and
>          printf(3)  type formatters.  As rpm already knows the type to print,
>          the type specifier must be omitted however, and replaced by the name
>          of  the  header  tag  to  be printed, enclosed by {} characters. Tag
>          names are case insensitive....

You can see the list of tag names that `rpm` knows about by running `rpm --querytags`.  It's a long list, so I won't reproduce it here in full.  However, some tags of interest include:

```
name
n
version
v
release
r
arch
nvra
nvr
description
```

Unfortunately for your *exact* use case, the `name` of the package in question is `centos-release`, not `centos` as desired, and the `release` is `4.1708.el7.centos`.

So the closest you can come to the output desired with pure `rpm` query formatting, is:

```
rpm -q centos-release --qf 'centos %{v}-%{r}\n'
```

(Note the use of a static string for "centos" rather than the `%{n}` tag, which would expand to "centos-release".  Also note the space, which you have in your desired output, although that may be a typo.)

On my test box this command produces:

```
$ rpm -q centos-release --qf 'centos %{v}-%{r}\n'
centos 7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If your release has a dash (or space) between `centos-release` and the number you can...

- replace "centos-release-" with "" using `sed` (`s/^centos-release.//`) and
- replace ".centos.*" with "" (`s/\.centos.*//`)
- stdout shows only the release

---

```
$ rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64

$ rpm --query centos-release | sed 's/^centos-release.//;s/\.centos.*//'
7-4.1708.el7
```